# How to select a range of data in tikz-pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

This is a subset of my table that I want to use to create a stacked bar chart:

[image]

Is it possible to select columns A through F for the first two rows and then select column G for the other rows to create a stacked bar chart?

This is my MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a table macro
Label A B C D E F G
Yes 0.24    0.92    0.52    0.96    0.52    0.24 nan
No 0.76 0.08    0.48    0.04    0.48    0.76 nan
High nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.08
Medium nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.4
Low nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.52
}\datatable

\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type, colnames from=Label, input colnames to=Label]\datatabletransposed{\datatable}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked, % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0, % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data, % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatabletransposed}{Label}, % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
    legend style={at={(0,0)}, anchor=north east,at={(axis description cs:0,-0.1)}}]
]
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue] table [x=Yes, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\addplot [fill=red!70!white] table [x=No, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\legend{Yes, No}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please add your MWE.

Comment: @ferahfeza I added my MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nan or NaN is not a good idea for missing data, at least for a stacked bar plot.

```
\documentclass[multi=tikzpicture]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread{% Read the data into a table macro
Label A B C D E F G
Yes 0.24    0.92    0.52    0.96    0.52    0.24 0
No 0.76 0.08    0.48    0.04    0.48    0.76 0
High 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.08
Medium 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.4
Low 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.52
}\datatable

\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type, colnames from=Label, input colnames to=Label]\datatabletransposed{\datatable}

%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\node{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\datatabletransposed};
%\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked, % Stacked horizontal bars
    xmin=0, % Start x axis at 0
    ytick=data, % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
    yticklabels from table={\datatabletransposed}{Label}, % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
    legend style={at={(0,0)}, anchor=north east,at={(axis description cs:0,-0.1)}}]
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue] table [x=Yes, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\addplot [fill=red!70!white] table [x=No, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\addplot [fill=green!70!blue] table [x=High, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\addplot [fill=red!70!white] table [x=Medium, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\addplot [fill=yellow] table [x=Low, y expr=\coordindex] {\datatabletransposed};
\legend{Yes, No}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]